# Javascript Unhiding Element Onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been playing around with javascript and I am trying to get the below to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function unhide(a) {
              document.getElementById(a).style.visibility = "visible";
              document.getElementById(a).style.display=block;
        }
</script>

<a onClick="unhide('id1')"><span> Remove</span>

<span id="id1" hidden="true">Are You sure?  | <a href="/forum/remove/id1"> Yes</a> / <a>No</a>   </span>
```

On click, I am trying to make the hidden element get shown. I am unsure why it isn't working, the logic seems right to me.

Cheers

Comment: Try using document.getElementById(a).style.display="block";

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of this code. I meant what are you trying to do here. Coz to me the code is total mess brother. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function unhide(a) {
          document.getElementById(a).style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById(a).style.display="block";
    }
```

block is undefined, "block" isn't

Answer (score 0):

You are using `hidden` **[html5 property](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute)** which has [**limited browser compatibility**](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/01/09/html5-hidden-attribute-browser-support/) as of now. Try to hide it initially by using css property `visibilty:hidden` which you change via your function's onclick event.

```js
function unhide(a) {
    document.getElementById(a).style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById(a).style.display=block;
}
```

```html
<a onClick="unhide('id1')"><span> Remove</span>

<span id="id1" style="visibility:hidden;">Are You sure?  | <a href="/forum/remove/id1"> Yes</a> / <a>No</a>   </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you out

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function unhide(a) {
              document.getElementById(a).style.display = 'block';
        }
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="unhide('id1')">Remove</a>

<span id="id1" style="display: none;">Are You sure?  | <a href="/forum/remove/id1"> Yes</a> / <a>No</a>   </span>
```

Let me know.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Only one point:
In `<script>` tag, all of words without quote is a reserved word or variable.So your code

```
document.getElementById(a).style.display=block;
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById(a).style.display='block';
```

Becase `block` is a attribute of display, not the others.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the hidden attribute.

So use this code instead:

```
function unhide(a){
    document.getElementById(a).removeAttribute('hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
$("#id1").hide();
};

$("#unhide").click(function(){
$("#id1").show();
});
</script>

<a id="unhide"><span> Remove</span></a>
<span id="id1">Are You sure?  | <a href="/forum/remove/id1"> Yes</a> / <a>No</a>   </span>
```

I hope this help you, please leave a comment if it's worked or not.